# Is creating a task and "Waiting" it the same as running something synchronously or awaiting an async method?

Tags: c#, async-await

Are the following code blocks equivalent if run on UI thread?

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => { await DoSomething(); });
task.Wait();
```

vs

```
await DoSomething(); //Or DoSomething.Wait();
```

Answer (score 3):

> Are the following code blocks equivalent if run on UI thread?

No they are not. The first one will block the *UI Thread*/*Message Pump*, the second won’t.

The first is trying to run an `async` method *Synchronously* and would fail any sane code review (in all but the rarest of circumstances). The first example should be changed to be the second example IMHO

> Is creating a task and “Waiting” it the same as running something
>   synchronously?

If you define *Synchronous* code as "*A bunch of statements in sequence; so each statement in your code is executed one after the other, and there is no code before the wait*". Then you can make this claim.

However, if you do something like this, then no

```
var task = Task.Run(SomeAwesomeTask);

// lots more code here

task.Wait();
```

Comment: What about DoSomething.Wait() ?

Comment: @lahsrah `DoSomething().Wait`, is asking for a deadlock

Answer (score 1):

> Is creating a task and “Waiting” it the same as running something synchronously?

The following code is; creating a task, creating a new thread, and running code on the new thread.

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => { await DoSomething(); });
```

It's important to know that *all of that happens*.

Assuming the signature:

```
async Task DoSomething()
```

All of the statements below are fundamentally different:

```
Task.Run(async () => { await DoSomething(); });
await DoSomething(); 
DoSomething().Wait();
```

I don't think I could go into detail about all of these (it's a lot of detail) but Stephen Cleary's has quite a number of posts that go into this detail ([Async and await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), [A Tour of Task, Part 1: Constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) [Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html), and [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)).

Comment: [It either creates one or uses an existing one from the threadpool (causing 2 threads to be used)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2).